# What is correct answer to the question お国は?

Tags: grammar

What is correct answer to the question お国は? 国はフランスです。or フランスから来ました。

Comment: Just to be certain -- this is a question in writing?  If spoken, what is the pitch accent?  おくには could parse out to either お国は ("your country?") or 奥には ("on the inside (of something)?") depending on the pitch and the context.

Comment: This is a question about country. I thought 「お国は」  means the same as "where are you from?". That's why i thought both answers Will fit here.

Answer (score 6):

It's generally advisable to answer a question in the way that it's being asked, so your first instinct would be correct. But I would leave the 「国は」out and just say 「フランスです」as the question already establishes that *your country* is the topic of the conversation, so there's no need to repeat that in your answer, as @frog kindly pointed out in the comments.

Comment: To add to the part about omission: when the topic has already been established with は, such as when asking a question, it shouldn't be repeated. Language instruction (at least in the West) loves to emphasize 'complete sentences', but the Japanese want nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

フランスから来ました means 'I am from France' whereas 国はフランスです means 'France is my country.' Hence, I'd recommend you to go with フランスです, which means 'France'